# Confused by combinatorical reasoning (n functional antennas, m defective problem)

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, graph-theory, combinations

This is an example question and solution straight out of "A First Course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross, on page 6 (fyi: all that's covered till this point in the book is the basic and generalized principles of counting, counting orderings with repeated elements i.e. permutations of PEPPER, combinations).

**Example 4c** Consider a set of $n$ antennas of which $m$ are defective and $n-m$ are functional and assume that all of the defectives and all of the functionals are considered indistinguishable. How many linear orderings are there in which no two defectives are consecutive?

**Solution** Imagine that the $n-m$ functional antennas are lined up among themselves. Now, if no two defectives are to be consecutive, then the spaces between the functional antennas must each contain at most one defective antenna. That is, in the $n-m+1$ possible positions$-$represented in Figure 1.1 by carets$-$between the $n-m$ functional antennas, we must select $m$ of these in which to put the defective antennas. Hence, there are ${n-m+1}\choose{m}$ possible orderings in which there is at least one functional antenna between any two defective ones.

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31276/choose-between-combinations-permutations), but I still don't get why the answer to this question has $n-m+1$. Can somebody please explain that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose there are a total of $7$ antennas, $2$ of which are bad. That means $n=7$, $m=2$, so the number of good antennas is $n-m=5$. We line up the five good ones, and ask where the bad ones can go:

__ G __ G __ G __ G __ G __

Each of the places where there's a line is an available spot for one (and no more than one!) bad antenna. Do you see how there are six available spots? That's $n-m+1$.

Comment: Oh, but six available spots$=5+1=n+1$, though... Ok, so then we subtract $m$ because of the $n+1$ spots, $m$ are ..taken..?, so then.....? Can you explain that part actually..?

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain that better.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Your answer was complete to begin with, I stupidly didn't interpret $n=5+2$ and misread it. Fully makes sense. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: One more thing... How do I prove that this answer is indeed correct? I would think induction: IH: need $n-m+1, \forall $n-m\in\mathbb{N}:n-m\lt k\in\mathbb{N}$. base:(n-m)=1 (draw diagram, there are clearly two spots, one on either side). base: (n-m)=2 (draw diagram, there are 3 spots, showing each possible spot a bad antenna could be inserted). inductive step:(n-m)=k: by IH, (n-m-1) needs (n-m-1)+1 spots, and adding one more good antenna will allow us to add exactly one more spot for a bad antenna, similar to the two base cases. QED. Is this a (good) way to prove the answer is indeed correct?

Comment: I don't think you need induction. It should be clear that, once $k=n-m$ good antennae are placed, there are exactly $k+1$ places available, namely, before each antenna $1$ through $k$, and also after the $k$th one.

Comment: Ok. It seems pretty clear, but I feel like I can never be too sure with combinatorics and probability.