# n total antennas of which m are defective, confused by reasoning?

Tags: probability

My problem follows from Sheldon Ross' A First Course in probability. And the question can be viewed in more detail here:

[Confused by combinatorical reasoning (n functional antennas, m defective problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288020/confused-by-combinatorical-reasoning-n-functional-antennas-m-defective-problem)

Basically there are a total of n antennas, of which m are defective. In how many ways can these n antennas be arranged so that no two defective antennas are side-by-side with each other?

I understand the reasoning presented in the answer to this problem in the link above. But consider the case where n = 9 and m = 7. In this case, can we say that there is no solution, because the given ${n-m+1}\choose{m}$ doesn't work?

In general, when can we say that there is no way to arrange the antennas such that no two defective cannot be placed side by side with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial coefficient will only make sense when $m\le n-m+1$, or $$m\le \frac{n+1}{2}$$